# Sidekiq Log Level not being set in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, sidekiq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running Sidekiq with Rails 5.2.3 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Following the instructions in the [Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging#default-logger-and-verboseness) in `initializers/sidekiq.rb` I've set:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
   config.logger.level = Logger::WARN
end
```

This works in the development environment however in production Sidekiq is still generating logs at the debug level. The Rails production logger level is set to `config.log_level = :warn`

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar, but opposite problem. My production log level was set to `WARN`, my Sidekiq log level was set to `INFO`, but I kept getting only `WARN` logs in production.

I finally figured out you must manually override the other loggers with `Sidekiq.Logging`

```
    Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
       config.logger.level = Logger::WARN

       Rails.logger = Sidekiq.logger
       ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Sidekiq.logger
       ActiveJob::Base.logger = Sidekiq.logger
    end
```

Credit to: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3651

Answer (score 0):

To use a single environment variable to control both `rails` and `sidekiq` logging behaviour.

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.logger.level = Logger.const_get(ENV.fetch('LOG_LEVEL', 'info').upcase.to_s)
end
```